# Registering 2.500 quantity differences in Excel?

Tags: excel

new here and quite ignorant at coding.

I got an issue here. I have a product inventory extracted from a Drupal eshop with 20.000 products.
I updated the Excel inventory with the true quantity. The quantity differences regard 2.500 products. We have not updated the Drupal eshop, unfortunately, when we should.

So this inventory changed over time. I have a new Excel inventory now with new products enlisted.
Every product has a unique serial number. **I need to register 2.500 quantity differences** and I am trying to find a way to do it **in Excel** without typing everyone of the 2.500 products by hand.

Every help is handy,
Thanks in advance,

Chris

PS. Can I hire someone to do it for me? Or is it something simple?

Comment: Thanks for this  challenging task, it would be great help if you share your demo requirement screenshot with desire output so we can figure out way by VBA aur any other logic in excel

Comment: Try this https://exceljet.net/index-and-match and share us how far you can get... ( :

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your problem. You have an Excel workbook with 20,000 products listed on your Drupal eshop. You also have another more recent Excel workbook with 2,500 products with serial numbers that match the first Workbook, and with updated quantities. You are interested in determining the differences between the updated products and the last time the Drupal site was updated.

If this is your situation, you could write a function called Vlookup which takes the serial of the updated quantity, finds that in your original inventory workbook, and then subtracts that from the new inventory. That gives you the difference. I have enclosed a screenshot. Pay attention to the colours in the formula, they will help you understand what is happening. Good luck!

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axZ37.png)